# Jasper Report Detail Band Data is not showing in Edge Browser

Tags: java, jasper-reports, microsoft-edge, export-to-pdf

I am facing issues regarding jasper reports is that my report's detail band data is not showing in edge browser. On other browsers the report is showing perfectly. 
I have updated the jars and software from 6.1 to 6.3 since 6.1 do not support edge browser but the issue still persist. I also have put frame behind the fields in detail band (for testing purposes) but nothing happened. 
   One thing i would like to add is that i selected Blank page in case of when no data type and report was showing blank report. What should possibly deduce from it.
One thing i would like to add is that this issue is happening in pdf report

Comment: Did you check this pdf with help of reader (on your local pc)?

Comment: @AlexK Thanks are help brother. I have rendered the report on browser. First thing i noticed that the browser do not show any utility tray that it shows on chrome while viewing the pdf(for saving and printing or navigation purpose). I right clicked and saved the report on system. The report saved on the computer still do not show any data.

Comment: `The report saved on the computer still do not show any data` - It means that the problem is not at browser but something wrong with your report

Comment: @AlexK that report do shows data on chrome browser. but in case of edge, it do not. That's why i think this might be due to browser compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. The reason behind the problem was two request were send to the controller of report. Due to that the data wasn't populated on the report. I added a code in my controller to avoid the dual request.

```
   String userAgent = request.getHeader("user-agent");
            System.out.println(userAgent);
            if(userAgent.contains("Edge")){
                String dlnaHeader = request.getHeader("getcontentfeatures.dlna.org");
                System.out.println(dlnaHeader);
                if(dlnaHeader == null ){
                    System.out.println("Looks like a fake extra Edge request on PDF viewer. Ignore it.");
                    //return null;
                    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    byte[] result = baos.toByteArray();
                    response.setContentType("application/pdf");
                    response.setHeader("Content-disposition","inline; ");
                    response.setContentLength(result.length);               
                    ServletOutputStream sos = response.getOutputStream();
                    sos.write(result);
                    return null;
                }
            }
```

After adding this code my report was showing data in detail band in edge browser. Hopefully it will help anyone else too.

Answer (score 0):

this helped me:
The issue is caused by the internal SWT browser behaviour still relying (by default) on IE11. Properly setting up the WebView2 component to force use the Edge engine should solve the issue.

Steps to resolve this issue:

1. From the official website download the Microsoft Edge WebView2 Runtime. Best solution is to choose the "Fixed version" x64.
2. Unpack the downloaded package to a convenience directory using a tool like 7-zip
3. Edit the Jaspersoft Studio Professional.ini file appending the following two Java properties (replace with the proper WebView files location):
   -Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=edge
   -Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.EdgeDir=C:\dev\webview

[resource](https://community.jaspersoft.com/knowledgebase/other-records/after-initial-loading-message-html-preview-stays-white-jss-811/)